# I did not use React Native SafeAreaView but it seems like i have been use. How can I do that?

Tags: react-native

This is the screenshot:

[image: Thats the screenshot]

But I don't want to be like this screenshot. I want to full page. I did not use React Native SafeAreaView but it seems like I have been use. I want to full page of this view but it's not. How can I do that?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store, persistor } from './stores/configureStore'
import AppNavigator from './navigators/Navigators';

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <Text>asdasdsad</Text>
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to hidden the status bar, you can try like this.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, StatusBar, View} from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { SafeAreaView} from 'react-native'
```

Simply wrap your top-level view with a SafeAreaView with flex: 1 style applied to it. Do remember to provide top-level layout style to the view under SafeAreaView, not the SafeAreaView.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingHorizontal: 20 }}>
    Other component here
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: thanks, but i want to make full screen with notch. I dont want to make any safe area padding bottom or top.